# Scala play: H2 "HikariDataSource has been closed."

Tags: scala, playframework

I am trying to run my tests in an in-memory database with this code:

```
class MySpec extends PlaySpec with OneAppPerSuite {

  Databases.withInMemory(
    name = "test",
    urlOptions = Map(
      "MODE" -> "MYSQL",
      "DATABASE_TO_UPPER" -> "false",
      "DB_CLOSE_DELAY" -> "-1"
    ),
    config = Map(
      "logStatements" -> true,
      "lazyInit" -> true,
      "username" -> "sa",
      "password" -> ""
    )
  ) { TestDb =>

    "DataManagementController" should {"connect" in { 
        TestDb.withConnection( conn => 0 )   // do nothing, but connect
    }}

  }
}
```

but I am getting this error: "HikariDataSource has been closed" before the test is executed:

```
[info] DataManagementController
[info] - should connect *** FAILED ***
[info]   java.sql.SQLException: HikariDataSource HikariDataSource (HikariPool-1) has been closed.
[info]   at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:79)
[info]   at play.api.db.DefaultDatabase.getConnection(Databases.scala:142)
[info]   at play.api.db.DefaultDatabase.withConnection(Databases.scala:152)
[info]   at play.api.db.DefaultDatabase.withConnection(Databases.scala:148)
[info]   at ControllerSpec$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(ControllerSpec.scala:37)
[info]   at ControllerSpec$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ControllerSpec.scala:37)
[info]   at ControllerSpec$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ControllerSpec.scala:37)
[info]   at org.scalatest.Transformer$$anonfun$apply$1.apply$mcV$sp(Transformer.scala:22)
[info]   at org.scalatest.OutcomeOf$class.outcomeOf(OutcomeOf.scala:85)
[info]   at org.scalatest.OutcomeOf$.outcomeOf(OutcomeOf.scala:104)
[info]   ...
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `OneAppPerSuite`, Play will start an app instance for each suite. In your case, you are creating a test database before the app is ready. So you have to invert the order of your code to something like this:

```
"DataManagementController" should {
    "connect" in {
        Databases.withInMemory(
          // Options and config here
        ) { TestDb =>
            TestDb.withConnection( conn => 0 )
        }
    }
}
```

You can also encapsulate the db initialization part to make it easier to use in each test that needs that db:

```
def testDB[T](block: Database => T) = {
    Databases.withInMemory(
      name = "test",
      urlOptions = Map(
        "MODE" -> "MYSQL",
        "DATABASE_TO_UPPER" -> "false",
        "DB_CLOSE_DELAY" -> "-1"
      ),
      config = Map(
        "logStatements" -> true,
        "lazyInit" -> true,
        "username" -> "sa",
        "password" -> ""
      )
    ) { block }
  }
```

and then use it like this:

```
"DataManagementController" should {
    "connect" in {
       testDB { db => db.withConnection(conn => 0) }
    }
}
```

Source: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaTestingWithDatabases

Comment: Thanks! it works. Do you know if this way of doing (creating a Database instance for every test) adds a performance overhead/is recommended?

Comment: Yes, it does (adds overhead). In general, I think it is advisable that each test have its db, so they are independent (ie there is no test that changes data in a way that can influence another). Of course, if  you have a lot of tests, creating all those db's will take some time (specially if you apply migrations/seed data). You will have to find what suits you better. Probably having a db initialized in each suite and reused by all of the tests can work just fine (ex if you make sure one test does not delete/update data that other one needs...)